# Error division by 0 YII

Tags: javascript, php, yii

creating a file for statistic, i'm having this error:

Internal Server Error

Division by zero

An internal error occurred while the Web server was processing your request. Please contact the webmaster to report this problem.

Thank you.

How can I solve this problem?
This is the code:

```
    $theme = Yii::app()->theme->name;
echo CHtml::cssFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/public/themes/'.$theme.'/css/jquery.jqplot.min.css');
echo CHtml::scriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/public/themes/'.$theme.'/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js');
echo CHtml::scriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/public/themes/'.$theme.'/js/jqplot.donutRenderer.min.js');
echo CHtml::scriptFile(Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/public/themes/'.$theme.'/js/jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js');
?>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="well">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%"><h1>Booking progress</h1><div id="flight" style="height:300px; width:500px;"></div></td>
                <td width="50%"><h1>Slot reservation progress</h1><div id="slot" style="height:300px; width:500px;"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var dataf = [
    ['Free to book', <?php echo floor(100 - $progress * 100); ?>],['Booked flights', <?php echo floor($progress * 100); ?>]
  ];
  var datas = [
    ['Free slots', <?php echo floor(100 - $sprogress * 100); ?>],['Reserved slots', <?php echo floor($sprogress * 100); ?>]
  ];
  var fplot = jQuery.jqplot ('flight', [dataf],
    {
      seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
          showDataLabels: true,
          dataLabels: 'percent'
        }
      },
      legend: { show:true, location: 's' }
    }
  );
  var splot = jQuery.jqplot ('slot', [datas],
    {
      seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
          showDataLabels: true,
          dataLabels: 'percent'
        }
      },
      legend: { show:true, location: 's' }
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

This is the controller

```
public function actionProgress()
    {
        $flc = FlightModel::model()->count();
        $bc = BookModel::model()->count();
        $progress = $bc / $flc;

        $slc = SlotModel::model()->count();
        $sc = SlotreserveModel::model()->count();

        $sprogress = $sc / $slc;
        $this->render('progress', array('progress' => $progress, 'sprogress' => $sprogress));
    }
}
```

Comment: What line does it say the error is on?

Comment: Have you contacted the webmaster to report the problem?  J/k, do this console.log(datas);console.log(dataf); before the line var fplot = ...

Comment: I suspect your data are all 0s in either or both datas and dafaf which cause the divide by 0 exception

Comment: How can I solve the problem? The data are inserted.

Comment: In your pie chart, what controls how much 'Free to book', 'Booked flights', 'Free slots', 'Reserved slots' to be?  Fix that your php script.

Comment: This is the controller public function actionProgress()
    {
        $flc = FlightModel::model()->count();
        $bc = BookModel::model()->count();
        $progress = $bc / $flc;
        
        $slc = SlotModel::model()->count();
        $sc = SlotreserveModel::model()->count();
        
        $sprogress = $sc / $slc;
        $this->render('progress', array('progress' => $progress, 'sprogress' => $sprogress));
    }
}

Comment: A `Division by zero` exception seems clear enough to me? One of the variables you use as divisor is zero somewhere ... Have you done any debugging yet? For example, print all variables used as divisor and find the one which is 0, then backtrack from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you do this

```
$progress = $bc / $flc;
$sprogress = $sc / $slc;
```

Either $flc or $slc or both are 0. Probably you are searching for a record that is not there.

Anything divided by 0 is infinity => that exact error.

You can probably change those 2 lines to

```
$progress = $flc > 0 ? $bc / $flc : 0;
$sprogress = $slc > 0 ? $sc / $slc : 0;
```

Comment: Thx! ;)
Take a look here on what I see...there's no graph
http://new.ivao.ch/rfe/stats/progress

Comment: But your error is no more. Start debugging the graph now.